# How do I estimate the 80% cumulative distribution point in scipy, numpy and/or Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distribution

Seaborn has a `kdeplot` [function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot) where if you pass in `cumulative=True`, then a cumulative distribution of the data is drawn. I need to annotate or figure out the value on the x-axis at which the cumulative distribution is 80% and then draw a vertical line from that value.

Is there a method in numpy, scipy or elsewhere in Python that may compute that value?

Comment: Have you tried using [scipy gaussian_kde](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.evaluate.html#scipy-stats-gaussian-kde-evaluate) to estimate the PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the cdf, then you can do the following. I'm not sure how your data is formatted, but assuming you have two arrays, one of x-values and one of y-values, you can search for the index of the y-value just above 0.8. The corresponding x-value would be what you're looking for. A quick way to do this, since your y-values should already be sorted, is:

```
import bisect
index = bisect.bisect_right(y_vals, 0.8) - 1
```

This is a nearest neighbor approach. If you want a slightly more accurate x-value, you can linearly interpolate between `index` and `index-1`.

Comment: I don't have a reference to the CDF. I don't think seaborn returns that object or the values associated with the CDF.

Comment: I realized that the CDF may be estimated from the raw data (sorted) and then apply what you stated.